# How to give all CPT a folder automatically based on their slug

Tags: custom-post-types, directory

This is what I have now and working:

```
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
global $post;

if ($post->post_type == 'amazon') {
$single_template = TEMPLATEPATH . '/amazon/single.php';
}
return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
```

But I want something like this:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template_folders_terms');
function my_single_template_folders_terms($template) {
global $wp_query;
foreach( get_post_type(array('public' => true, '_builtin' => false)) as $post_type ) {
if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$post_type->slug}/single.php") )
        return TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$post_type->slug}/single.php";
}
return $template;
}
```

I got this error;
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: I think you want to get the post type of the current post, otherwise you'll always get the template associated to the first type that appears in the list of all types.

Comment: yes, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second function is wrong. [`get_post_type($post)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) excepts the current post object or post ID or any post object or ID given to it. You are using the arguments for [`get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types) for `get_post_type`, which fails the function which in turn gives you the error in your `foreach` loop.

To rectify your function, use something like this:

```
add_filter('single_template', 'my_single_template_folders_terms');
function my_single_template_folders_terms($template) {
    global $post;

    $post_type = get_post_type($post);
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$post_type}/single.php") )
        return TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$post_type}/single.php";

    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a small bug in my code due to copy&paste from your code. Corrected it. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, can't vote bcos of low reputation.